# autoit IE click on a button in a website

Tags: autoit

I am trying to open a link by clicking on button inside a website.
This is the element :-

```
   <div class="btn3">Like</div>
```

I tried this

```
$oBtn.classname  = _IEGetObjById($oIE, "Like")
_IEAction($oBtn, "click")
```

not working. any help. Please.

Comment: Clicking all the likes? Can't see a legitimate reason for that to be honest...

Answer (score 3):

You are doing it all wrong.
Try reading the help file.

This will work

```
Local $oInputs = _IETagNameGetCollection($oIE, "div")
For $oInput In $oInputs
    If $oInput.classname == "btn3" Then _IEAction($oInput, "click")
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use $oBtn.classname only if you create an internet application object or an xml object with autoit. OR if you use _IETagNameGetCollection()

Here is an example:

```
#include <IE.au3>

Local $oIE = _IE_Example("form")
Local $oInputs = _IETagNameGetCollection($oIE, "input")
Local $oBtn
For $oInput In $oInputs
    if $oInput.class = "btn3" Then
        $oInput.Click
        ExitLoop
Next


_IEQuit($oIE)
```

Of course you will need a little modification to the code since we know nothing about the website you are trying to automate

Comment: There is a bug in autoit that happens sometimes, so you shouldn't  use $oInput.class = "btn3". Use $oInput.class == "btn3" or String($oInput.class) = "btn3"